# Typescript says it does not satisfy the constraint when really it does

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the thing : I have two almost identical components, only one is controlled (i.e. gets a `variables` prop), the other is not (gets a `defaultVariables` prop). This `variables` object must be a subtype of `Filters`. The uncontrolled version adds default filter values. So some keys from `Filters` must be set to optional when it comes to `defaultVariables`.

This gives me the following :

```js
// Tool for making only some keys optional :

type Optional<TVariables, K extends keyof TVariables> = Omit<TVariables, K> &
  Partial<Pick<TVariables, K>>;

// The filter base variables found in every TVariables :

type Filters = {
  search: string | null;
  sort: string | null;
  sortOrder: number | null;
  limit: number;
  page: number;
};

// Component props, controlled and uncontrolled versions :

type Props<TVariables extends Filters> = {
  variables: Omit<TVariables, 'page'>;
  // ... other props, irrelevant here
};

type UncontrolledProps<TVariables extends Filters> = Omit<
  Props<TVariables>,
  "variables"
> & {
  defaultVariables: Optional<Props<TVariables>["variables"], "limit">;
};
```

**But**, error on the last line :

```
Error:(467, 62) TS2344: Type '"limit"' does not satisfy the constraint 'Exclude<keyof TVariables, "page">'.
```

But really, this doesn't make sense. With the constraint `Filters` set to the generic `TVariables`, `Exclude<keyof TVariables, "page">` should by definition at least be `"search" | "sort" | "sortOrder" | "limit"`.

So what's the problem here ?

Comment: Is it perhaps an issue with the fact you exclude page but not limit, and limit does not have a default value? (I'm not a TS user, just trying to help :))

Comment: Nop because `limit` must not be excluded. It has to be part of the type for `variables` (and optional but present in `defaultVariables`)

Comment: Looks like TS bug, it has no sense

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36316 created a bug about that will see

Comment: @MaciejSikora Thanks, let's see how this plays out.